# Facebook graph API image caption search from within the query

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I had previously used a FQL query to look for hashtags in an Authed users photo album for an app that I developed. However, I need to make a new app and the only graph API version that is available to new apps is v2.2. This version does not allow using the FQL language in queries. So as a workaround I use the graph API to query a users uploaded images and then parse through each one with a regex to detect hashtags. This is obviously significantly more intensive on my end now, so I was wanting to know if there is a "matching" command or something close that I can use in the actual graph API query.

Is that possible?

The FQL query I used was:

select caption,src_big,created,object_id from photo where owner=me() AND strpos(lower(caption),lower("#"))>=0

I really just need to be able to use strpos() in the query and I'll be good. Am I out of luck and I just need to have it all done on my end?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no matching search query in the Graph API.

You can make the request smaller by only asking for what you need for the regex

`me/photos/uploaded?fields=name`

Use your regex to find those with #

Then do a second call to only return photo IDs that match.